# FlxTilemap CSV loading with height of 0

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I am trying to load a CSV file into a FlxTilemap like so:

```
map = new FlxTilemap();
map.loadMap(Assets.getText(AssetPaths.map__csv), AssetPaths.tileset__png, 16, 16, 0, 1);
add(map);
```

However, when I test it using `lime test neko`, the map does not display.

I am using a horizontal tilemap with 16x16 tiles saved as tileset.png, and a csv map saved as map.csv. I have been able to accomplish this before using exactly similar code.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: [Here is my CSV file](https://gist.github.com/AgentEpsilon/2056f0e84168f2d1a7b0)

Comment: Is the CSV large? Can you paste its text as well?

Comment: Just added the CSV in a Gist

Comment: I can get a tilemap to display using your exact code. What version of HaxeFlixel are you using. Also, out of curiosity can you provide a link to the tilemap you're trying to load?

Comment: [Tilesheet](http://i.imgur.com/HLzXAEO.png)
I'm using HaxeFlixel version 3.3.6

Comment: The tilesheet looks fine to me. I guess I'd have to see your State's code to see where it possibly goes wrong.

Comment: That's really it. There's only two other lines instantiating a FlxSprite, and commenting those out does nothing. I'll try reinstalling HaxeFlixel.

Comment: Well, here is my State with the tilemap loading if it helps at all: http://pastebin.com/uppWXNNA

Comment: I created a brand new project and used your code, and it doesn't work. Maybe it's just something wrong with my machine.

Comment: Here's your tilemap in action: http://i.imgur.com/AdGHNLT.png. Do you have the latest version of Haxe installed?

Comment: Yep, 3.1.3 . I'm really not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by installing the development version of HaxeFlixel. I guess it was a bug in v3.1.3? Anyways, unless you are having the same problem, you shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you had a new line at the end of your CSV. That was a bug in FlxTilemap.loadMap, but it is fixed in the development version.